# Virtual dressing systems

Tags: api, real-time, augmented-reality

Which softwares can provide me a fairly good library and API to create a small virtual dressing application. I am looking into the capabilities of Pinta, Filters, Imagemagick etc.

Comment: Really hard to tell from the question what you need, since you don't specify what kind of image manipulation you plan on doing.

Answer (score 0):

[FLARToolkit](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en) gives you excellent augmented reality capabilities. It's writtin using as3. You can use [papervision3d](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) or [away3d](http://www.away3d.com) in conjunction with FLARToolkit to make yourself a very good app.